# Why doesn't IntelliJ Idea recognize my Spek tests?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, junit, kotlin

I have a Gradle-based Kotlin project with some [Spek](http://spekframework.org/) tests, which are based on JUnit and should be compatible with Idea.

But I don't see a "Run" menu item in the context menu.

[image: Context menu]

Why? What do I need to do in order to be able to run Spek tests in Idea like other JUnit tests?

Here's my `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.4'
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://dl.bintray.com/jetbrains/spek"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-M3'
  }

}

apply plugin: "kotlin"
apply plugin: "application"
apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'

junitPlatform {
    filters {
        engines {
            include 'spek'
        }
    }
}

mainClassName = "com.mycompany.myproduct.AppKt"

sourceSets {
  deploy
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven {
    url "https://dl.bintray.com/jetbrains/spek"
  }

}

dependencies {
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
  compile 'org.telegram:telegrambots:2.4.2'
  compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'
  compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-core', version: '1.1.3'
  compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.1.3'
  compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.6.1' 
  testCompile  'junit:junit:4.11'
  testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version"
  testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version: '2.0.2-beta'
  testCompile 'org.jetbrains.spek:spek-api:1.1.19'
  testRuntime 'org.jetbrains.spek:spek-junit-platform-engine:1.1.19'
}

test.testClassesDir = project.tasks.compileTestKotlin.destinationDir

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
  gradleVersion="3.1"
}

run {
    jvmArgs = ["-Xmx100m", "-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError", "-XX:HeapDumpPath=/[...]/log/memdump.log"]
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': mainClassName,
                   'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect {"$it.name"}.join(' ')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you installed the [Spek plugin for IntelliJ](https://github.com/raniejade/spek-idea-plugin)?

Just search for `spek` in the IntelliJ plugin settings.

Comment: I feel so dumb right now...thanks for this :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Junit 4.11, you can remove this from your build.gradle:

```
junitPlatform {
    filters {
        engines {
            include 'spek'
        }
    }
}
```

Then add this above your test class declaration:

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform::class)
```

Source: http://spekframework.org/docs/latest/#setting-up-legacy